# jQuery - calculate a responsive margin for an element

Tags: jquery, responsive-design, margin, evaluate

I would like to calculate a responsive margin-top for the footer of a navigation - it should always be placed 50px over the bottom. I wrote this code but it doesn't work - anybody can help me?

```
(function () {
$(window).resize(function () {
    var navHeight = $("nav").height();
    $("nav footer").css({ "margin-top": navHeight - 50 });
}).resize(); });
```

This is the stylesheet for the elements so far, pretty basic.

```
nav { position:fixed; top:0; left:0; width:320px; height:100%; padding:100px 0 0 0; }
nav footer {  }
```

I really need this to be done with jQuery - no CSS solutions. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

You just need css!

```
.nav.footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 50px;
}
```

**DONE!** ;)

Example code: http://jsfiddle.net/QKLQx/

Comment: That will seperate the footer from the rest of the navigation - that's not what I want. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in plain CSS:

```
nav {
    position: relative;
}

nav footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

Any element with `relative` or `absolute` position resets the offset parent of its descendant elements, meaning that you can position elements contained inside `nav` relative to `nav` rather than the document.

Comment: Even this will disturb the structure - I really need this to be done with jQuery. Sorry!

Comment: You could simply add those styles dynamically to `nav` and `footer` with jQuery in your resize event handler.  Otherwise we kind of need to see markup and CSS for `nav` and `footer` and any other relevant elements, because the ideal method of positioning `footer` will depend on the markup and CSS.

Comment: The way I started to code is pretty much the optimal solution for me. If that code would work, it would be the best for me. Thanks!

Comment: @user2825956 right I understand - but can you post the HTML markup structure that `nav` and `footer` exist in and their corresponding CSS definitions? The effect of various properties used for positioning such as `top` and `margin-top` for example varies drastically based on contextual CSS properties (for example `display`, `position`, `float` properties of the element and its ancestors, and so forth).  It is hard to troubleshoot without this context info.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the CSS solution below by @Ennui should work with your jQuery attempt as follows:

```
(function () {
$(window).resize(function () {
    $("nav").css("position", "relative");
    $("nav footer")
        .css("position", "absolute")
        .css("bottom", "0px")
        .css("height", "50px");
}).resize(); });
```

Comment: Now that he's updated his post with the CSS I see this solution won't work exactly - since `nav` is `position:fixed` it does not set offset/positioning context like a `relative` or `absolute` positioned element.  All he needs to do is add a full height `position:relative` inside `nav` that wraps `footer` and the rest of the `nav` content, then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

my code...
http://jsfiddle.net/7rHeR/

maybe we don't understand your problem... or you don't really know what you want...

hope this helps!

**js:**

```
function getNavFooterDistance() {
    var distance = $(".nav.footer").offset().top - $(".nav").offset().top;
    console.log("Distance " + distance + "px" );
}

$(function() {
    $(window).resize(function () {
        getNavFooterDistance();
    });

    getNavFooterDistance();
});
```

**css:**

```
.nav {
    position:relative;
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color: blue;
}
.nav .footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 320;
    background-color: red
}
```

**html:**

```
<div class="nav">
    <div class="nav footer"></div>
    bla<br>bla<br>bla<br>bla<br>bla<br>bla<br>
    bla<br>bla<br>bla<br>bla<br>bla<br>bla<br>
    bla<br>bla<br>bla<br>bla<br>bla<br>bla<br>
</div>
```